# how to solve vector output problems?

Tags: python, nlp, vec

["Hello, I would like to ask, is there an error in the code in this image that causes the output to remain 0? I'm having problems with incorrect output from the code."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H99QY.png)

I've tried paying attention to the coding, but the vector output is 0

Comment: I don’t really understand what you’re trying to do here. Why does your get_vector return a list of zeros when it’s empty, and otherwise returns just a number? Also please put your code in a formatted code block instead of an image next time since it makes it easier to look through and test.